How to add 1 day to date if a sheet has a specific name in Excel
I work with a very large workbook in Excel with 600+ sheets on it. In about half of them, I need to add one day to the date listed in a cell but only if a worksheet has a specific name. Is there a way to automate this or am I going to be stuck doing it manually?
I have only tried doing this manually.

Just to be clear, you want to change one date in one cell on a specific worksheet by one day? Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value + 1 would  do what I think you want.

Yes, kind of.  Each sheet of the workbook has a date listed in cell A3, but if the name of the sheet contains a certain word, then I need to add a day the date in A3.

In VBA we can write a subroutine that will:

Loop through every sheet in your giant workbook
check the sheet name
If the sheet name matches whatever pattern you are searching for, update a cell.

This will look something like:
Sub UpdateDates()
    
    'Declare a variable to hold the sheet in each loop's iteration
    Dim sht as Worksheet
    
    'Loop through every worksheet in this workbook
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        'Check if the sheets name has the word "bob" in it
        If Instr(sht.name, "bob") > 0 Then
        
            'We have a match, add one (day) to a date in cell A1 of this sheet
            sht.Range("A1").Value = sht.Range("A1").Value + 1
        End If
    Next sht
End Sub

I did not test this. It might be buggy. There is no way to undo any changes made by this subroutine so be careful.

This worked! I pretty much copied and pasted it and then updated it to the field I needed and the cell I needed the day added to and it worked! Thank you so much! You saved me hours and hours of tedious work!

@LaurenLull If it worked, then you should mark the answer as correct

You should be able to do this by using VBA if you are proficient with it.
Take a look at this question:
How to insert a function into a cell with VBA?
You could loop through your sheets and add a function to a specific cell if the sheet name meets a criteria
